# Detect device orientation

Tags: css, device-orientation

Running a responsive single-page app, there are box objects with content.  These are intended to have background images.  However, for hand-held devices, orientation becomes a problem, as the boxes width and height proportions change.

Detecting devices and viewport sizes has not been a task built on uniform procedures.  At appears to me that, assuming users have relatively modern browsers, CSS3 and invoking `@media screen and (orientation:landscape)` is the safest bet.

Assuming that images will be cropped in both a horizontal and a vertical version and a tag with orientation-less coding

```
<div class="box" style='background:  url("https://somewhere.amazonaws.com/general-purpose-images/splash.jpg") no-repeat fixed; background-size: 100% 100%; background-attachment: scroll;'>
```

How can this be effectively toggled according to orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a div with a class for the image

```
<div class="img_a">
```

Then define the CSS rules for the required images according to orientation or [any other media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries) you might need to implement

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait)
  { div.img_a 
      { background: url(https://[...]img_a.jpg) no-repeat fixed; }
  [...] }
@media screen and (orientation: landscape)
  { div.img_a 
      { background: url(https://[...]img_a_horizontal.jpg) no-repeat fixed; }
  [...] }
```